# Writing an equation as a glm in R

Tags: r, glm, prediction

I have a multi-variable equation that I have concluded after some analysis. I would like to write this equation in the form of a glm in R. I am doing this so that I can use the "predict" and other functions on this equation. Would that be possible?

Here are the details of my equation

```
intercept:15.67
variable1 coefficient: -3.2
variable2 Coefficient -0.8
```

I know it sounds as simple task but I couldn't find a function to convert an equation into a glm (something like "as.glm"!) Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: That's because the equation of a (generalised) linear model is only part of a (generalised) linear model. There's all sorts of other parts like the residuals and variances that you don't have. So it would have to be another class of object, although it could still have a `predict` method...

Comment: I am cool with that! Can you please show me how to make it that other "object" or "class"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick hack of a class of *linear* functions. I'm fairly sure something better must exist somewhere... But anyway:

```
linear <- function(betas){
    betas = matrix(betas, ncol=1)
    ret = list(
        pred = function(z){
            (cbind(1,z) %*% betas)[,1]
        }
        )
    class(ret)="linear"
    ret
}

predict.linear <- function(object, newdata, ...){
    object$pred(newdata)
}
```

Then you can do:

```
> l1 = linear(c(15,1,2))
> predict(l1,cbind(1:10,12:21))
 [1] 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67
```

Which is just:

```
> 15 + 1*(1:10) + 2*(12:21)
 [1] 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67
```

ie intercept plus explanatory variables * coefficients.

Note this relies on the order of the columns in the matrix, rather than the names of variables in a data frame. As I said, there's probably a better, more usable implementation out there so I don't want to develop this much further. Have a print method:

```
print.linear <- function(x,...){
    cat("Linear interpolator\n")
    cat("Parameters: ",x$betas)
    cat("\n")
    invisible(0)
}
```

So it now says:

```
> l1
Linear interpolator
Parameters:  15 1 2
```

when you print it.

If you really want **generalised** linear models then you'll have to specify a family (Poisson, Binomial etc) and a link function in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this in the past so i wrote a helper function to create a fake glm object called [makeglm](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/ae299d8f3760f02de6bf). There's actualyl a bunch of stuff you need to set up so you can use `predict()` including specifying classes for columns. The function itself requests a data.frame from which it can infer data types. Here's an example of how you would use it.

```
#sample data
set.seed(15)
dd <- data.frame(
    X1=runif(50),
    X2=factor(sample(letters[1:4], 50, replace=T)),
    X3=rpois(50, 5),
    Outcome = sample(0:1, 50, replace=T)
)

# fit standard model     
mymodel<-glm(Outcome~X1+X2+X3, data=dd, family=binomial)
predict(mymodel, type="response")

#create a "fake" model and still use predict
newmodel <- makeglm(Outcome~X1+X2+X3, family=binomial, data=dd, 
    -.5, X1=1, X2=c(b=1.5, c=1, d=1.5), X3=-.15)
predict(newmodel, newdata=dd, type="response")
```

Comment: We call this "preparing to shoot yourself in the foot". Mucking with object internals, and still calling it an object of that class is very very naughty. Don't try `fitted(newmodel)` or `resid(newmodel)`. I like to think we should develop proper objects for this, if such things don't already exist. Until then, practice hopping.